# Microsoft graph api create folder using path returning 'invalidRequest'

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The following error is returned by graph api:

```
  "error": {
"code": "invalidRequest",
"message": "[child] A null value was found for the property named 'id', which has the expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "36d65bbb-2f6e-485c-b2b9-5bb7fdb76d19",
  "date": "2017-09-30T00:24:06"
  }
}
```

The code I'm using:

```
var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/joba:/children";
var folder = new ItemResource { name = "nested", folder = new FolderFacet() };
var response = api.PostAsJsonAsync<ItemResource>(url, folder).Result;
response.ThrowWhenUnsuccessful();
return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ItemResource>().Result;
```

That is, I'm trying to create a nested folder named **nested** in the **joba** folder (which is inside *root*).
It doesn't work... I even tried to escape the colon `:joba:` but it doesn't work either. The same request works just fine in [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

What is wrong with mine?

**EDIT**
Fiddler request

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/wdg:/children HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <OMITED>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 268
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"id":null,"createdBy":null,"createdDateTime":null,"eTag":null,"cTag":null,"description":null,"lastModifiedBy":null,"lastModifiedDateTime":null,"name":"85923635-56af-4902-82da-babd95165c6b","parentReference":null,"webUrl":null,"folder":{"ChildCount":null},"file":null}
```

Comment: At a glance your request looks as expected, and I do not repro it using code that's pretty much identical to yours. If you could capture the request and response that's being sent on the wire to Graph and add that to your question that would help (exclude the auth token :))

Comment: looking at fiddler request, I've figure it out.. I'm using the same model to retrieve data and post data, and I'm posting **null** things there and graph doesnt like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PostAsJsonAsync` uses Json.NET under the covers, which by default will serialize properties with null values. Since omitting a value is treated differently to deliberately specifying a null value, when this occurs it triggers the OneDrive API to consider the request invalid, because a null value is specified for a non-nullable field.

To get around this you can add the following attribute to the nullable properties on the `ItemResource` type:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

Alternatively, you could use Json.NET to directly serialize the object and provide an appropriately configured `JsonSerializerSettings` instance, followed by a call to `PostAsync`.